# Compare two character arrays in C language

Tags: c

What will compare if two character arrays in C language are compared using "==" ?

The answer was Not Equal.

```
char string1 [] = "Hello";
char string2 [] = "Hello";

if (string1 == string2){
    printf("Equal");
} else {
    printf("Not Equal");
   }
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Check [strcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

Comment: it will compare the base address of arrays

Comment: This is a super-common FAQ. For those who answered it anyway: you can find a list of canonical dupes in the [C tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info). Scroll down to FAQ -> Strings. Then close vote as dupe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What will compare if two character arrays in C language are compared
> using "==" ?

Arrays base address will be compared.

If you want to compare the contents of the arrays you need to use `strcmp`.

Answer (score 1):

`string1` and `string2` are array names that get converted to pointers to `char`, so using `==` will compare those pointers.

Pointer values are memory addresses that are different for each `char` array, so it is the correct output that you have.

If you want to compare the 2 arrays, then `strncmp` is an option.

Answer (score 1):

To better understand run this program and read [strcmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string1 [] = "Hello";
    char string2 [] = "Hello";
    // checking base address of string1 and string2, which will not be equal
    if (string1 == string2) {
        printf("Equal : string1 = %u and string2 = %u\n", string1, string2);
    } else{
        printf("Not Equal : string1 = %u and string2 = %u\n", string1, string2);
    }
    // strcmp checks the contents that are stored in string1 and string2
    if(strcmp(string1, string2) == 0) {
        printf("Equal\n");
    }else {
        printf("Not Equal\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You just use strcmp to check if the two string are equal or no

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string1 [] = "Hello";
    char string2 [] = "Hello";
    if(strcmp(string1, string2) == 0)
    {
         printf("Equal\n");
    }
    else 
    {
         printf("Not Equal\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```